# Optimise MySQL for regex queries or better DMBS for faster regex queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, nosql

I'm currently using a MySQL Database with only one table where I'm searching for products with a regular expression. The table has the following columns: id, title, date and description. I'm looking for a way to speed up those regex queries, where I'm searching for multiple keywords or real regular expressions in the description column which has the type text. The database contains over 1 million products. Is there a way to speed up those queries, because they take several minutes to execute or should I switch to a different DBMS?

Best regards and thanks for help

Comment: Look into a full text index.  Regular expressions are not the best tool for these purposes.

Comment: There is no way to index for generic regex matching (not just in MySQL).